# Linux bash script not returning output when running remotely via ssh but returns output when running locally

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have created a bash script on linux which I can invoke remotely via ssh.  For some reason, the shell script produces the expected output only when I run the command **directly on the box**.  However, if I run the *exact same command* with the exact same input (from remote box **via ssh**), no output is received.

Interestingly enough, I created a "usage" string which prints out when you pass in no arguments and if I invoke the script via ssh without arguments, I see the usage string.  This tells me that the ssh client **can** receive output from the remote shell script.

I've tried invoking the command from another linux box on the same subnet.  I've tried invoking the command from Windows (cygwin/open ssh).  In both of these cases, the behavior is the same.

I'm completely stumped.  How can I get the output of a shell script invoked via ssh.

In case you're wondering what's in the shell script, it just produces a list of files modified in the last 20 minutes, then invokes a python program to process those files:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <cluster>"
    echo "-----------------------"
    echo "Example: $0 mycluster"
    exit
fi

clusterName=$1


find /mylogs/abc/123/mydir -mmin -20 -name "mylog*.log" > /home/myuser/file_names.txt
python filterDatesInFiles.py | sed -e "s/^/${HOSTNAME},\/mylogs\/abc\/123\/mydir\/^*~%$/"
```

in case you're interested in the python script, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime, sys, time
# Example log line:
# [2/20/18 10:03:27:187 GMT-07:00] 0000001c SystemOut     O ....
f = open("/home/myuser/file_names.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line) == 0:
         continue
    f = open(line)
    fileLines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for fileLine in fileLines:
        fileLineStripped = fileLine.strip()
        if len(fileLine) == 0:
            continue
        if not fileLine.startswith("["):
            continue
        fields = fileLine.split(" ")
        dateTime = fields[0].split("[")[1] + " " + fields[1]
        dtObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f")
        currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        d1_ts = time.mktime(dtObj.timetuple())
        d2_ts = time.mktime(currentTime.timetuple())
        minutesAgo = int(d2_ts-d1_ts) / 60
        if minutesAgo <= 15:
            print fileLineStripped
```

However, I know this script works, because, as I said, I can run this script directly on the target box and it produces the correct output.

Here is how I'm invoking it via ssh:

```
ssh myuser@mylinuxserver '/home/myuser/logScraper.sh mycluster'
```

Note - when I run that ssh command with "-v", here is the output I get:

```
$ ssh -v myuser@myhost.mydomain.com '/home/myuser/logScraper.sh mycluster'
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Connecting to myhost.mydomain.com [123.45.67.61] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 93:a2:73:80:08:d5:cc:ad:78:c0:df:48:68:cb:b0:f4
debug1: Host 'myhost.mydomain.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/known_hosts:40
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myremoteuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myuser@myhost.mydomain.com's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to myhost.mydomain.com ([123.45.67.61]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending command: /home/myuser/logScraper.sh mycluster
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2080, received 2392 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4000.0, received 4600.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Any clues why I cannot get the output when running via ssh?

Comment: Voting to close because minimal example is missing. Further, the "linux" tag is misplaced, please read the description of the tag before using it. Lastly Linux is written with a capital "L", it's a name, but that's just a minor flaw.

Comment: The newline between the `>` and the filename is a syntax error on bash. I'm curious which shell you have where it works.

Comment: I just fixed that newline

Comment: BTW, *how* you're invoking your command over SSH matters, and I don't see that included in the question.

Comment: (...and as an aside -- in general, you shouldn't ever use newlines as delimiters to distinguish between filenames: Filenames *are allowed to contain* newlines. You don't want someone who runs `mkdir -p /tmp/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n' && touch /tmp/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/hello` to make your script mess with `/etc/passwd`, for example. The safe character to use for the purpose is NUL, which is the whole reason `find -print0` exists).

Comment: Run your script with logging: `ssh myuser@mylinuxserver $'PS4=\'${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}+\' bash -x /home/myuser/logScraper.sh mycluster'`

Comment: I've added the ssh command I use to invoke it - both via cygwin on Windows box and on another Linux box in same subnet

Comment: (If it works when invoked that way, then edit the script to add a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang at the top).

Comment: Hmmm - not sure why you put $'PS4=\'${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}\' bash -x /home/myuser/logScraper.sh mycluster' on a separate line?

Comment: (err, note that I edited the PS4 to have a `+` after the `LINENO` expansion; that's important, as the last character of PS4 is repeated in output to reflect nesting depth).

Comment: @user3038640, huh? What separate line? That's just StackOverflow's line wrap. Comments don't allow explicit newlines -- I couldn't put a newline in a comment if I wanted to.

Comment: Nothing logged to stderr, even, or just no *output*? And btw -- have you looked at `/home/myuser/file_names.txt` to see if gets updated when this happens?

Comment: 2nd question first - yes, file_names.txt does get updated (with one file name/path on one line), and this data gets sent into the python program.  Re 2nd question, there is no output at all - not stdout, nor stderr

Comment: If you run `exec >/path/to/stdout 2>/path/to/stderr` in your script as a separate line (after the shebang), do the files being directed to get populated with contents?

Comment: If I run it "locally" the stdout file gets populated with expected output and stderror is empty.  When I run it via ssh, both are empty

Comment: Is SELinux enabled on this box? Is it in enforcing mode?

Comment: not sure - here is output of uname -a `Linux myhost11 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 13 10:46:25 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Do you have a `getenforce` command? What's its output? Note that it may be in `sbin` rather than `bin`, and thus only in the default PATH for `root`.

Comment: try `ssh -t` or -tt, sometimes it wants tty for something

Comment: OK - I finally have the real answer.  In the .bash_profile of the user running the script, I had the following line:

    `TZ='America/Phoenix'; export TZ`

But my .bash_profile either was not executing while logging in remotely, or just that timezone was not being respected when ssh'ing in. 

The solution was to add that line to the script itself.  Since the script has date logic in it, that explains why no data was returned and no error was displayed while invoking via ssh, but when running it locally, there is data output.

I hope this saves someone some time.

Comment: Where and what was the date logic?

Comment: In the shell script it was `find /mylogs/abc/123/mydir -mmin -20` and in the python script it was `minutesAgo = int(d2_ts-d1_ts) / 60`